# how to extract fields like severity, time, message etc from kubernetes logs using fluentd

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd

How can I extract different fields like severity, time, stream, message from kubernetes logs using fluentd. I have multiple patters of logs coming from kubernetes. how can i extract fields from different kinds of patterns using fluentd

sample error log -  `{"log":"2019-09-06 21:57:50.864 DEBUG 1 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] class  : error message \"\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2019-09-06T21:57:50.864955417Z"}`

regex I am using - `^(?:{"log":"(?<time>\d+(?:-\d+){2}\s+\d+(?::\d+){2}\.\d+)\s"*(?<level>\S+) (?<pid>\d+) --- \[(?<thread>[\s\S]*?)\] (?<class>\S+)\s*:\s* (?<message>[\s\S]*?)(?=\g<time>|\Z).*)`

I am getting pattern not found error while using regex. below is my fluentd config

```
 <source> 
   type tail 
   path /var/log/containers/*.log
   pos_file /var/log/es-containers.log.pos
   tag kubernetes.* 
   format /^(?:{"log":"(?<time>\d+(?:-\d+){2}\s+\d+(?::\d+){2}\.\d+)\s"*(?<level>\S+) (?<pid>\d+) --- \[(?<thread>[\s\S]*?)\] (?<class>\S+)\s*:\s* (?<message>[\s\S]*?)(?=\g<time>|\Z).*)/
   time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
   read_from_head false
 </source>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have been through this. I found playing with regex pretty unhealthy :).

This is how I solved it .

1. I made the application to write the log as a json. In my case it is a java application using log4j. So could easily convert it to a json.
2. So application logs began looking like `{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2019-09-06 11:33:24,987","thread":"http-nio-8090-exec-5","file":"AccountService.java","line":"51","message":"A sample info log","trace":""}`
3. Now the kubernetes logs wraps the application logs with log object as a json.
4. With a bit of help from the [blog](https://medium.com/@joatmon08/application-logging-in-kubernetes-with-fluentd-4556f1573672), I could get all the information as attributes in elastic search.

Comment: thank you for your response. we have logs coming from third party and it would be complex to change it to json format. is it possible to extract based on regex. I am able to identify the regex but fluentd is failing with patttern not match error

Comment: Initially tried https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-grok-parser , this became very complex as the log contained multiline stack traces, messages, random sysouts etc..